# Media Query not reading from Widths 479px to 767px?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have three media queries that range like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 479px)
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width 767px)
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)
```

The issue is that my website doesn't read the styles in the width range of 479px to 767px which is something I do not understand, any assistance with this of suggestions are very much liked, thanks!

Comment: can you replicate the error using a page and the styles associated with these media queries? that will help us understand more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo you forgot the colon at the `(max-width 767px)` it should read like the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 479px)
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)
```

Here is a snippet

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 479px){
  body{background:green;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){
  body{background:yellow;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px){
  body{background:red;}
}
```

Comment: The character missing is a `:`, not a semi-colon  (`;`). Well spotted nonetheless.

Comment: @connexo my bad mean't colon thats what i put in the answers snippet, anyway good lookin out though thanks I edited the answer.

Comment: That is well spotted indeed, thank you! I am still new to using this method so I am not adjusted to looking for these kind of mistakes but I am in C# lol, thanks man!